# <select> (Drop-Down List) side by side with <input> text. jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'am using jQuery Mobile and trying to place an text input and select dropdown side by side.

If I use this code

```html
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="number" id="convert-weight-from" placeholder="Text input" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <select id="weight-unit">      
      <option value="kilo">Kilo</option>
      <option value="hekto">Hekto</option>
      <option value="gram">Gram</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I get this result.

[image: fi]

But if I use this code

```html
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="number" id="convert-weight-from" placeholder="Text input" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="number" id="convert-weight-from" placeholder="Text input" value="" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I get this result

[image]

As you can see, they are on the same vertical level if I use `input` but not if I use the `select`. I'am not using any other css or framework right now.

Comment: It doesn't looks like this for me: http://jsbin.com/luxini/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/controlgroup/ go to page bottom "Textinputs".